# Getting the Title of an MP3 throws "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException"

Tags: java, android, mp3, media-player, mediametadataretriever

Why does this code throw a IllegalArgumentException?
I want to show the Title of an MP3-File which is located at the "raw" folder

```
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.willy_william_ego);
            MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
            Uri uri = (Uri) Uri.fromFile(new File("android.resource://com.hthl.kellergassen_app/raw/willy_william_ego"));
            mmr.setDataSource(getActivity(), uri);
            String title = mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);
```

Comment: Stacktrace, please.

Comment: What is **willy_william_ego**? More importantly, why is there no **.mp3** link in your code?

Comment: what do you mean with Stacktrace? @Fildor

Comment: willy_william_ego is the song. I saved it under this name in the raw folder. And no Codeexample has am .mp3 link at the end of the song...and with .mp3 it also does not work @VC.One

Comment: A Stacktrace is that errormessage with "Excpetion blah blah at ... at ... at "

Comment: @Fildor you can find the stacktrace in the answers below

Comment: Check my answer which your stacktrace confirms: This line is the interesting one from the stacktrace btw - android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(MediaMetadataRetriever.java:77)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're getting the issue in setDataSource, it'll be because the URI you're passing in isn't valid for some reason - most likely because the file couldn't be found. Are you sure it's present with that name and doesn't have a file extension?

From the Javadoc...

*void setDataSource (Context context, Uri uri)*

*Sets the data source as a content Uri. Call this method before the rest of the methods in this class. This method may be time-consuming.*

*Parameters*
*context    Context: the Context to use when resolving the Uri
uri Uri: the Content URI of the data you want to play*

**Throws
IllegalArgumentException    if the Uri is invalid
SecurityException   if the Uri cannot be used due to lack of permission.**

UPDATE -  Having looked at your code, it seems you're using the hard-coded String `com.hthl.kellergassen_app` as the package name, but that's not right. According to the stacktrace it's `com.htlhl.kellergassen_app` - note the extra "l" in "htlhl" (this is in the String you use to create the URI).

Comment: thanks for the answer...the uri has to be valid, because I can play the right file with my mediaplayer

i start the mediaplayer so:
uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getActivity().getPackageName()+"/raw/ger_station_01");
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), uri);

and then setDateSource(uri) should be invalid? I dont think so...

Comment: Definitive answer -- Look at the code for MediaMetadataRetriever and you can see that that's why it's throwing the IllegalArgumentException. Whether you agree or not, that is what's happening! :)

Comment: It looks like you do have the name wrong. See the update in my edited answer.

Comment: yeah, thats right but unfortunately I changed it to getPackageName() and it still does not work...
I think I have to take the Name of the file instead of the Metadata...so i wll safe it under the title and so on..

Comment: and it would be really nice if you could explain me how to read the stacktrace

Comment: It's well worth learning how to read stacktraces, and isn;t that hard once you get used to it. It's covered pretty well in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors